# Prestashop 1.7 - Access a module on the entire website

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I installed a module (PS 1.7.5) and handles data only when it is on its route :

```
https://mywebsite.com/en/themodule/main
Route : module-ps_themodule-main
```

I would like the data to be accessible on the whole website, not just on his route.
I have to do an override of the module or extend the FrontController instead ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use any hook which is available on all pages and display your information there